# How do I know what power supply to use with a circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage

I've bought this tiny microcontroller called a [Photon](https://www.particle.io/prototype#photon). It comes with a micro USB connector for powering the device (which I am connecting to my computer). I've read somewhere that the maximum voltage that can be applied to the pins of the device is 3.3V.

I'm an electronics newbie. The Photon did not ship with a power adapter. I want to connect it to a wall socket so that it is always on. I'm thinking of using a [5V 1A iPhone adapter](http://www.bosscases.co.uk/images/31/136331057034.jpg), but how can I be sure this will not destroy the circuit?

In general, is there any way I can know what adapter is safe to use with a circuit?

Here is an image of my device:

[image]

Comment: With a USB power supply it is not likely to cause damage to the circuit. The issue that will more frequently rise is that the power supply is not powerfull enough. In your case: 1A = 1000mA. The tiny microcontroller boards often don't have a switched dc-to-dc voltage converter. That means the 3.3V is generated by burning the difference to heat using a "linear voltage regulator". This means that there is also 1000mA available at 3.3V. Now I would have a look in the component's datasheet to look for the power consumtion. https://docs.particle.io/datasheets/photon-datasheet/ tells: 80mA, so ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The board can be powered via USB, so the 5V adapter is OK.

The required voltage of 3.3V is generated on-board from the 5V supply. The maximum voltage for the inputs is 3.3V.

You can find the datasheet here: https://docs.particle.io/datasheets/photon-datasheet/.

In general you should try to find the specification. You can also look at the schematics and the specification of the parts.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will generally work for DC supplies:

Does the circuit require constant current (rather than constant voltage). e.g., certain LED configurations? Then go to **Constant Current**. Otherwise use * Constant Voltage**.

**Constant voltage**

1. What voltage does the load require?
2. What is the maximum current of the load?
3. Use a supply of the required voltage with a current rating of *at least* the maximum current of the load.

**Constant current**

1. What is the current required by the load?
2. What is the voltage across the load when that current is running through it?
3. Use a supply of the required current with an output voltage of *at least* the required voltage.

In your Photon case it is powered by USB which always has 5 V on the red and black wires. If the chip requires 3.3 V then there must be a voltage regulator on the Photon. So let's apply the Constant Voltage approach:

1. The load requires a 5 V supply.
2. The Photon will require very little current (a few mA) but the loads it is controlling could be much more - let's say 20 mA per LED and we have ten, so 200 mA.
3. 1 A (1000 mA) USB chargers are readily available. One of these will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

**USB is a standart.** It means all USB power supplies all over the world *must* provide 5v between power and GND rails.

On the power specifications, you can always find that information on the datasheets. This board must be using a voltage regulator to provide 3.3v to the micro-controller.

Also, you can always use an adapter with a higher rated current. The other way around depends on the actual needs of the product.

So, you can use a 1A adapter instead of a 200mA, but not the opposite, unless the product draws less than 200mA.